# gchart not appearing

Tags: gwt, gchart

i am using this simple example from GChart

```
      public void displayGChart(final ArrayList<ResultDTO> result){

        GChart c = new GChart();
        c.setChartTitle("<b>x<sup>2</sup> vs x</b>");
        c. setChartSize(150, 150);
        c. addCurve();
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
             c.  getCurve().addPoint(i,i*i);
         c.getCurve().setLegendLabel("x<sup>2</sup>");
         c. getXAxis().setAxisLabel("x");
         c. getYAxis().setAxisLabel("x<sup>2</sup>");


    verticalPanel.add(c);
    verticalPanel.add(new Label("test"));
}
```

when i run the application ,I got NO errors , and i can see this "test"  on my browser but nothing else , no chart is appearing..

i have added the jar and

```
            <inherits name='com.googlecode.gchart.GChart' />
```

Any Idea what could be the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please call c.update(); after adding the chart to the panel, like this:

```
    verticalPanel.add(c);
    c.update();
    verticalPanel.add(new Label("test"));
```

This is also described here: http://clientsidegchart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/gchart/client/package-summary.html:

> No charts? These examples only define the chart. To actually display it, you must add and update it:

```
    // Use this typical GChart boilerplate to test out these examples:
    GChart gchart = new GChartExample00(); 
    RootPanel.get().add(gchart);
    gchart.update();
```